# Keepalive, routing issue, "no destination available"

Tags: linux, routes, kernel, keep-alive

I am setting up a failover server for our website using keepalive.

I have been following this tutorial that feets exactly my needs:
- http://blog.profitbricks.de/failover-und-loadbalancing-loesung-bei-profitbricks/

For a couple of days, everything worked well with keepalive and the virtual ip.

Suddently, the VIP is unreachable on port 80 but still reachable on port 443.

Facts:

1. `ip addr show` => i do see the VIP only in one of the frontends.
2. From the frontend itself, if i query it using it's public IP (the
   non vip one) it does work on port 443 and 80.
3. From anywhere if i use the virtual ip and https, i can reach our application and i do see it in the http server logs.
4. In syslog i have weird messages like this one for every test i do that use port 80 on the VIP ==> /var/log/kern.log <== Nov 18 15:00:07 localhost kernel:
       [14045.457450] IPVS: rr: TCP 'the virtual ip':80 - no destination
       available

Hopefully it is not in production yet and if you can help me on that i would be really thankful :)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone search for the terms in this question:

- The port 443 was reachable because the server that had the VIP was correct and there was no load balancing on port 443.
- The port 80 was unreachable because i didn't setup the iptables correctly on one of the two servers and load balancing was supposed to be done using NAT (bypass_ipvs.sh).

Conclusion: if you need failover and no loadbalancing (which is uncommon) then the mentionned configuration is too much and not adapted.